# Jimp error: No matching constructor overloading was found

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, jimp

I'm trying to create a meme command with my bot that uses Jimp to add text onto an image the user sends with the command. It works, but whenever something doesn't go to plan (e.g. someone not sending the image, someone not sending the text that needs to be applied to the image, etc.) it gets an error and crashes my bot. Here's my code:

```
case "meme":
const [topText, bottomText] = args.slice(1).join(" ").split(",");
msg.channel.startTyping();
if (!args[1]) msg.channel.send("You need to give the text you want to apply to the image!");
Jimp.read(msg.attachments.first(), (err, lenna) => {
  Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_128_WHITE).then(font => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    lenna
      .resize(1280, 1080)
      .quality(100) // set quality
      .print(font, 75, 20, {
        text: topText,
        alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
        alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
      }, 1100)
      .print(font, 75, 900, {
        text: bottomText,
        alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
        alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
      }, 1100)
      .write("./tmp/" + msg.author.id + ".jpg"); // save
  });
});
for (i = 0; i < (1); i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    msg.channel.send({
      files: ["./tmp/" + msg.author.id + ".jpg"]
    })
    msg.channel.stopTyping();
    for (i = 0; i < (1); i++) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        fs.unlinkSync("./tmp/" + msg.author.id + ".jpg")
      }, 3 * 1000)
    }
  }, 3 * 1000)
}
break;
```

Error:

```
(node:32440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No matching constructor overloading was found. Please see the docs for how to call the Jimp constructor.
    at Jimp.throwError (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@jimp\utils\dist\index.js:35:13)
    at new Jimp (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:502:85)
    at _construct (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\construct.js:19:21)
    at C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:1016:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.Jimp.read (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:1015:10)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:53:18)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
(node:32440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32440) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:32440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\tmp\652940695585292299.jpg'
(node:32440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink './tmp/652940695585292299.jpg'
    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1053:3)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\lqshkiwi\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:80:32)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './tmp/652940695585292299.jpg'
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6P6i6CuS

Comment: Please edit extra information into the question next time

Comment: oh ok, this is my first question here so I'm not really familiar with the etiquette :)

Comment: In my case, this problem occured when I passed `undefined` to `Jimp.read`.

Answer (score 0):

Without know what specific error you're trying to handle against, the best way is to wrap your entire section of code in a `try/catch`. In the catch portion, you can `console.warn` the error and hopefully use the logs to debug this with more details.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I have a pastebin with the error right here: pastebin.com/6P6i6CuS

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a `return` statement to exit the logic if the user didn't follow the proper commands. When the user didn't provide the argument, I'm guessing `msg.attachments.first()` returns `undefined` which is why Jimp errors.

```
if (!args[1]) {
  return msg.channel.send("You need to give the text you want to apply to the image!");
} 

try { // it's good to have a try catch when dealing with asynchronous code
  Jimp.read(msg.attachments.first(), (err, lenna) => {
...
```